# Mysql Left Join with Group By and Between

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am having trouble to create a select query that will retrieve all users id that isn't in the games and availability between dates.

Example: Retrieve all users that are not between dates `2017-08-10` and `2017-08-12`.

Get `[3 , 4, 5]`

Users

```
| Id | Name     |
| 1  | Jonh     |
| 2  | Mark     |
| 3  | Caroline |
| 4  | David    |
| 5  | George   |
```

Games

```
| Id | User_Id  | Start_Date | End_Date   |
| 1  | 1        | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 |
| 2  | 1        | 2017-08-12 | 2017-08-13 |
| 3  | 4        | 2017-08-13 | 2017-08-14 |
```

Availability

```
| Id | User_Id | Start_Date | End_Date   |
| 1  | 1       | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-25 |
| 1  | 2       | 2017-08-10 | 2017-08-17 |
| 1  | 3       | 2017-06-20 | 2017-07-10 |
```

I am using Laravel 5.4 but I'll glad if the answer is on Raw or Eloquent.

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Have you tried anything? Gonna need some more details before we can help you. If you haven't tried anything, please do that and come back with the specific errors you've encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from users u
where not exists (
        select 1
        from games g
        where u.id = g.user_id
            and (
                g.start_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12'
                or g.end_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12'
                )
        )
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from Availability a
        where u.id = a.user_id
            and (
                a.start_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12'
                or a.end_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12'
                )
        );
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/EWRQY42765)

Another way using `LEFT JOIN` would be:

```
select distinct u.*
from t_users u
left join games g on u.id = g.user_id
    and (g.start_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12'
        or g.end_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12')
left join availability a on u.id = a.user_id
    and (a.start_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12'
        or a.end_date between '2017-08-10' and '2017-08-12')
where g.user_id is null and a.user_id is null;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/PUYQW8329)

Comment: great approach.  is it more efficient than what i propose?

Comment: @tonygil - It depends on the data. Also added another solution based on left joins with demos for both.

Answer (score 0):

I dont like using human readable dates because of MMDDYYYY vs DDMMYYYY, but rather use UNIXTIME dates, so i will pseudocode accordingly

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Games ON Users.Id = Games.Id_User
LEFT JOIN Availability ON Users.Id = Availability.Id_User
WHERE ISNULL(Games.Id) AND ((Start_Date > EndDateUnixtime OR End_Date < StartDateUnixtime)  OR ISNULL(Start_Date) OR ISNULL(End_Date))
```

You can use this logic to convert DMMYYYY dates to unixtime in case you keep on recording human readable dates.

```
unix_timestamp(str_to_date('30/05/2011','%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: Assume the dates are actually `datetime` fields, which they really should be.

Comment: I assume nothing, i follow an old saying reapeated ad nauseam by my former mechanics teacher: "When i ASSUME i make an ASS out of U and ME".  :)